# Netgear gateway. After enabling QoS, 2.5ghz is no longer visible. Model #R6220

Tags: router, gateway, netgear-router

I enabled QoS on my gateway for a game. I then realized that the 2.5ghz network no longer showed up. Only the 5ghz network was there. I disabled QoS and it didnt fix it. I reset the router to factory settings twice. I manually upgraded the firmware. I tried all the channels and modes but the 2.5ghz network will not show up. it looks fine in the routerlogin page but i cant find it or connect to it.

Comment: Can you see other networks? Are you on Windows? What is your wifi adapter?

Comment: This could be hardware related. I.e the 2.4ghz radio is on its way out. These routers are supported by third party firmware. Give OpenWRT a shot on it, if the radio doesn't come back up I would replace the router.